# Inconsistent behavior in np.arange?

Tags: python, numpy

When I run:

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(14.1,15.1,0.1)
```

I get:

```
array([14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 14.4, 14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 15. ])
```

yet when I run:

```
np.arange(15.1,16.1,0.1)
```

I get:

```
array([15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 15.5, 15.6, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16. , 16.1])
```

What is up with the missing `15.1`? Why does the output in one case show the final number and in the other case not?

I have read the documentation on [numpy-arange](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). It states that the "interval does not include ***stop*** value, except in some cases where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out."

My question is:
**How to get the code to behave consistent?**

I am iterating over a list of paired numbers (e.g. 4 and 15, or 44.2 and 46.4) and for each pair, I want to create a list with steps of 0.1 between the pairs (e.g 4 and 4.5 would be: 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5). But it is important that the code behaves consistent.

Comment: From the doc: `When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is due to [floating point precision](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Taking a look at the actual decimal representation of the floats without any rounding will make it clearer:

```
15.1%1
# 0.09999999999999964

16.1%1
# 0.10000000000000142
```

Note that just like python's `range`, `np.arange` does not include the `end` in the created range, hence unless the floating point error results in a value greater than the step in the `end` of the range, it will not be included. That is the case of the first `float`, which has a decimal part lower than `0.1`.

The docs do suggest using [`np.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) when using a non-integer step, since the results can be inconsistent, precisely for the above reason.
Moreover it includes a `endpoint` parameter, which allows you to do:

```
np.linspace(14.1,15.1, 11, endpoint=True)
# array([14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 14.4, 14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 15. , 15.1])
```

And, as @divakar suggests, to generalize you can set `num` as:

```
start = 14.1
stop = 15.1
step = 0.1
num = 1+int((stop-start)/step)

np.linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint=True)
# array([14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 14.4, 14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 15. , 15.1])
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains my issue, now how to fix it?

Comment: Use `np.linspace` as already mentioned in the comments. The difference is that you'll have to specify beforehand the amount of samples to generate @J.A.Cado

Comment: @yatu Good insight with `%`. Think you can create a custom one with `1+int((stop-start)/step)` as `num` to have `step` as an input arg to linspace.

Comment: Thanks @divakar much nicer with a general approach