# numpy arrange oddly including endpoint when it shouldn't

Tags: python, numpy

Can anyone help with best practices for avoiding this type of problem?

in: `np.arrange(1, 2.2, .2)`
out: `array([1. , 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2. , 2.2])`

Must have something to do with binary/base10 difficulties, as

in: `np.arrange(1, 2.2, .2)[6]`
out: `2.1999999999999997`

python version:  3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]

numpy version: :  1.16.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent behavior in np.arange?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217178/inconsistent-behavior-in-np-arange)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, answered my own question (rly just wanted to post on stackoverflow).

It's best to use `numpy.linspace(start, stop, num=50, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None, axis=0)`, and just set num to (start - stop)/spacing (+1 if endpoint=True).