# Why does 3.2 in numpy.arange(3, 3.9, .01) return False?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using [NumPy's arange() method](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html?highlight=arange#numpy.arange) and trying to figure why my value, which is seemingly in range, does not return True when applied.

```
3.0 in np.arange(3, 3.9, .01)
```

Returns True which is expected. However, the following returns false:

```
3.2 in np.arange(3, 3.9, .01)
```

I also verified the values the np.arange() expression generates. The IDE showed 3.2000 as  a valid value, adding the trailing zeros did not change the result.. In addition, the following expression returns True, which again I expect:

```
1.7 in np.arange(0, 3, .01)
```

Comment: You might not have 3.2, check the values in the `array` property, I have `3.1999999999999957` and `3.2099999999999955`. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `in` (`__contains__`) uses `==` testing.  With floats it is better to use `np.isclose`, which tests the absolute difference.  This handles the small differences (on the order of 1e-15) that we can expect in float values.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are using np.arange() with a non-integer step, which is [known to be inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62217178/inconsistent-behavior-in-np-arange). Taken from [np.arange() documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.

```
ranger = np.arange(3,3.9, .01)
linspacer = np.linspace(3,3.89,90)

print(3.2 in ranger)
print(3.2 in linspacer)
```

The first statement will return False, where the second statement will return True.